# Are links without anchor text bad for seo?

Tags: hyperlink, seo, anchor

we are currently redesigning our website and certain elements have the following structure:

```
<div class="Item"> 
  <div class="Text">
    <span class="Name">Name of Profile</span>
    <span class="City">City</span>
  </div>
  <div class="Link">
    <a href="http://example.com/"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question would be, if an empty anchor text is bad for SEO and Google. How do they handle this kind of links currently?

I did a search on this issue but only found very old entries which said that Google even banned the website, but back in 2002.

Any information or suggestion on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why is the link there in the first place? Aren’t your users supposed to click them?

Answer (score 4):

By using empty anchor text you will not prevent from indexing your pages but **you will loose a good opportunity to add relevance to your pages**.

#### Empty anchor text is not critical

- Google does not need an anchor text to follow a @href URL (bot will be able to find your pages)
- It's impossible to get a website banned from Google for this.

#### But anchor text is really helpful for ranking

Google uses anchor text in order to qualify the resources you create a reference to.

In consequences if a page got links with "example" as anchor text pointing to itself, this page relevance on "example" request will increase.

So **better do not let empty anchor text and choose wisely the words (or keywords)** you use in it.

Answer (score 0):

Empty Anchor text is not bad for SEO.But You loose your visitable in major search engine.so it is better to add more targeted keywords is good.